# trying to extract objects form string with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

this is the string that I want to get objects from the curly brackets so i can get the ID.
"{"id":101,"value":"cartman","prefix":"@"} a sds {"id":109,"value":"Mr. Mackey","prefix":"@"}"

Comment: JSON.parse is what you want to look at for interpreting JSON strings into an object: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: When i use json am getting error in for the string.